# Some literature on voice

Tags: voice

Are there any books or articles on voice per se, the ways of development, improvement, the process of sound creation etc.?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes.  Can you be more specific, so that you can get a *good* answer?  What exactly are you aiming to learn, what level are you at, etc.?  We generally prefer "How can I ..." questions so that rather than limiting yourself to books you can also take advantage of the experience of and tips from other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geography of the Voice by Jo Estill is a book that gives very detailed information on the physiology behind singing. It also gives examples of simple physical actions (such as raising eyebrows and smiling) that put the muscular and other physical mechanisms behind singing into place. These methods teach you how to sing any style of music in a healthy way that won't damage your vocal mechanism (vocal folds).

www.estillvoice.com has all of their resources for sale online.  There are companion cds that are very helpful to the process.

Answer (score 1):

I was helped "The Zen of Screaming" is an instructional DVD by Melissa Cross.

You can order this DVD here https://www.melissacross.com/vocal_training_products.php
or find it in any kind of torrent trackers or file hostings.